# Image caching does not work for me using GeowebCache integrated in Geoserver 20.4

Tags: geoserver, wms, geowebcache, cache

I have configured gwc cache system and enabled layer for cache and global services over OGC Services on global settings.
When I try this URL I get this:

$ curl 'http://myserver/geoserver/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=-180,-90,0,80.33032694475760138&SRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=846&HEIGHT=800&LAYERS=ws:mylayer&FORMAT=image/png'

GWC Error

##### 400: class org.geowebcache.mime.ApplicationMime cannot be cast to class org.geowebcache.mime.ImageMime (org.geowebcache.mime.ApplicationMime and org.geowebcache.mime.ImageMime are in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @3524ee20)

**Looking in geoserver.log for this request, I get:**

2022-05-18 12:53:48,806 ERROR [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - class org.geowebcache.mime.ApplicationMime cannot be cast to class org.geowebcache.mime.ImageMime (org.geowebcache.mime.ApplicationMime and org.geowebcache.mime.ImageMime are in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @eb5471c) http://vgis.dipalme.org:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms
2022-05-18 12:53:48,806 ERROR [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - Request failed
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.geowebcache.mime.ApplicationMime cannot be cast to class org.geowebcache.mime.ImageMime (org.geowebcache.mime.ApplicationMime and org.geowebcache.mime.ImageMime are in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @eb5471c)
at org.geowebcache.service.wms.WMSTileFuser.(WMSTileFuser.java:325)
at org.geowebcache.service.wms.WMSService.getFuser(WMSService.java:356)
at org.geowebcache.service.wms.WMSService.handleRequest(WMSService.java:319)
...

Comment: Problem solved or still exist?